# Cypress security warning NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment

Tags: node.js, cypress

When running some tests in Windows 10
I am getting this warning:

```
Action Test
(node:560) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
```

How to fix this? is this native to cypress configuration or some setting I forgot to add?

Comment: Did you get solution for this @Daniel Vianna

Comment: The only time I've seen this is when I am purposely setting that env variable in an attempt to bypass self-signed certificate warnings. Maybe you have it set for that reason in your package.json?